# Unresolvable git merge conflict

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I have worked on this problem for three days and I can't find a solution for this merge conflict. Can somebody please help me out here?

[image: unresolvable git conflict]

Comment: Is there any trailing space?

Answer (score 3):

This happens often to me, some hove GIT thinks this is conflicted (maybe there is an extra white space or something) and just duplicates it. Just delete it by hand and commit changes before you push.